# Android app dies after loading library (API 10)

Tags: android

I am trying to make the app work on API 10 and above.
The app is working on Android API 18, 21 without a problem, but when testing on Android 2.3.6 (API 10), the app just closes, no warning no exceptions no errors. here is what i get in the Logcat:

```
    --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
11-12 18:15:24.539        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-12 18:15:24.539        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-S5830/GT-S5830:2.3.6/GINGERBREAD/XWKTQ:user/release-keys'
11-12 18:15:24.559        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 13551, tid: 13551  >>> com.digiwork.alleviewscan <<<
11-12 18:15:24.559        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 80b12d3c
11-12 18:15:24.559        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 80b7167c  r1 00000003  r2 80b11eea  r3 80b70860
11-12 18:15:24.559        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 80b7166c  r5 80b71c34  r6 80b7166c  r7 00000000
11-12 18:15:24.559        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 4438dc64  r9 bea8e530  10 00000000  fp 4438d850
11-12 18:15:24.559        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 80b00000  sp bea8e388  lr 80b12418  pc 80b12d3c  cpsr 80000010
11-12 18:15:24.559        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0  414000003f800000  d1  3ff0000000000000
11-12 18:15:24.559        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ d2  bf80000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
11-12 18:15:24.559        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ d4  0000000000000000  d5  3ff000003f800000
11-12 18:15:24.559        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ d6  bf8000003f800000  d7  404000003f800000
11-12 18:15:24.569        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
11-12 18:15:24.569        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
11-12 18:15:24.569        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
11-12 18:15:24.569        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
11-12 18:15:24.569        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ scr 20000012
11-12 18:15:24.619        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00012d3c  /data/data/com.digiwork.alleviewscan/lib/libDMSImageWatermark.so
11-12 18:15:24.619        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  lr 80b12418  /data/data/com.digiwork.alleviewscan/lib/libDMSImageWatermark.so
11-12 18:15:24.619        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around pc:
11-12 18:15:24.619        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ 80b12d1c eaffffec e1a00004 e1a01006 ebfffe33
11-12 18:15:24.619        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ 80b12d2c e1a05000 eafffff3 0005e334 0005e32c
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ 80b12d3c f2c00010 e59f201c e3a01000 e580100c
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ 80b12d4c e2801004 e79f2002 e2822008 f441078f
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ 80b12d5c e5802000 e12fff1e 0005e054 e92d4010
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around lr:
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ 80b123f8 0005e9cc e92d4038 e1a04000 e59f30d0
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ 80b12408 e79f3003 e2833008 e4803010 eb000248
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ 80b12418 e7e02154 e262500a e3a01000 e1520001
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ 80b12428 e584102c 15841030 e1a010a5 e59f30a4
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ 80b12438 13a0c009 13a00001 03a0c00a 01a00002
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e348  b0009468
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e34c  bea8e3bc
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e350  b00099d0
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e354  ffffffe0
11-12 18:15:24.629        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e358  ffffffff
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e35c  80b11380  /data/data/com.digiwork.alleviewscan/lib/libDMSImageWatermark.so
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e360  00000015
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e364  80b04384  /data/data/com.digiwork.alleviewscan/lib/libDMSImageWatermark.so
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e368  b000e4bc
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e36c  b0003c4d  /system/bin/linker
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e370  80b71668
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e374  b00140cc
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e378  b000e430
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e37c  80b70000
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e380  df002777
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e384  e3a070ad
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 bea8e388  80b11ee8  /data/data/com.digiwork.alleviewscan/lib/libDMSImageWatermark.so
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e38c  0005ee74
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e390  80b71c34
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e394  80b11f0c  /data/data/com.digiwork.alleviewscan/lib/libDMSImageWatermark.so
11-12 18:15:24.639        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e398  80b706e0
11-12 18:15:24.649        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e39c  00000003
11-12 18:15:24.649        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3a0  00000004
11-12 18:15:24.649        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3a4  b00037f5  /system/bin/linker
11-12 18:15:24.649        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3a8  b000e514
11-12 18:15:24.649        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3ac  b000e510
11-12 18:15:24.649        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3b0  00002750
11-12 18:15:24.649        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3b4  b00038a9  /system/bin/linker
11-12 18:15:24.649        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3b8  00072000
11-12 18:15:24.649        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3bc  afd00000  /system/lib/libc.so
11-12 18:15:24.649        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3c0  00000024
11-12 18:15:24.659        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3c4  b000e430
11-12 18:15:24.659        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3c8  80b70d50
11-12 18:15:24.659        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ bea8e3cc  b000e430
    --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
11-12 18:15:25.029      186-210/? I/BootReceiver﹕ Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_08 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
11-12 18:15:25.039        89-89/? I/DEBUG﹕ dumpstate /data/log/dumpstate_app_native.txt
```

What can i do? What can cause the issue? 
I would love to try the app on a different phone, but it is hard to find Gingerbread phones, like i had issue finding this one even.

Tried removing all the functionality of the app, to bear minimum, but same thing, same result.

If i dont load the library, the app starts and gives error Missing Native Library, but i need the libraries for the app to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess. The phone you are testing on is a ARMv6 architecture (armeabi) while the newer ones are on ARMv7 (armeabi-7a/armeabi-7a-hard). Can you confirm that your library is appropriate for that architecture.

Comment: hmmm, good question, but i dont know how to confirm or check that. 
From the provider of the libraries, says that it has been tested on 2.3, 4.1, 4.4 etc. 
Other than that, i dont know how to check them. Is there a way to convert , compile them for armv6? Because all i did is create the armeabi folder and copy them there.

Comment: I would go back to the library provider to get a list of what are the supported architectures. Just saying that it was tested on 2.3 doesn't mean they couldn't be using NEON instructions - something that I would expect from something labelled 'ImageWatermark'. Side note - the Nexus S which supported 2.3 is CortexA8 (armeabi-7a)

Comment: thanks a lot for the help Morrison. I will contact the library provider. 
On another thing, how can i limit the app to be available only to armeabi-7a and API 10? And also do you know what would be the percentage of Api 10 cell phones, that uses armv6 compared to armv7?

Comment: In theory if you put your library binary just in armeabi-7a folder it should just default that that only, and Google Play store shouldn't show it devices without it. I'm wondering if your library vendor encountered this on ICS: https://moodstocks.com/blog/article/ice-cream-sandwich-why-native-code-support-sucks/ and just released a armeabi-7a library only.

Comment: thanks for the tip Morrison. It might be the case, i will be contacting the vendor and find out this. Thanks again for the help.